# Does HTML5 ban th cells from tbody?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, web-standards

I have the following markup as a part of a Razor view:

```
<table>
  <caption>Presidents</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Born</th>
      <th scope="col">Died</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Washington</th>
      <td>1732</td>
      <td>1799</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With the "target schema for validation" set to HTML5, Visual Studio complains thusly:

> Warning    1   Validation (HTML5): Element 'th' must not be nested within element 'tbody tfoot'.

Is this really true? If so, could someone link to the spec?

My understanding was that using `<th>` for row headers was not just legal but encouraged. It certainly seems fairly common, I could link dozens of tutorials explaining (seemingly sensibly) that it helps with accessibility.

Is this a VS bug? A real change coming with HTML5 (a good one? a bad one?)? What's the story?

Comment: Does your action code, instead of `<!-- etc -->`, contain any invalidly nested code? A `<th>` without a `<tr>` for example?

Comment: Gareth, good question, but no it doesn't. I just meant to suggest that there is more than one similar row. I tried it with only the one and it only reduced the duplicate copies of the same warning (one for each such cell).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> My understanding was that using `<th>` for row headers was not just legal but encouraged

As far as I know, this was always legal in HTML 4 (and possibly its predecessors), and hasn't changed in HTML5.

[W3C's HTML5 validator](http://validator.w3.org), while still experimental, reports no warnings or errors. Then again, I'm sure the HTML5 validation Visual Studio is using is experimental as well since HTML5 itself hasn't yet been finalized.

The [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html) on marking up tabular data, specifically [section 4.9.13](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#table-examples), shows the use of `<th>` within `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` to scope row data:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
   <th>2008
   <th>2007
   <th>2006
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Net sales
   <td>$ 32,479
   <td>$ 24,006
   <td>$ 19,315
  <tr>
   <th>Cost of sales
   <td>  21,334
   <td>  15,852
   <td>  13,717
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Gross margin
   <td>$ 11,145
   <td>$  8,154
   <td>$  5,598
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th>Gross margin percentage
   <td>34.3%
   <td>34.0%
   <td>29.0%
</table>
```

So it's perfectly legitimate to have `<th>` elements inside `<tr>` elements inside either a `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>`. As it should be anyway, since table headings aren't just found on table headers.

Comment: I agree. I created [issue 656626](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/656626/html5-validation-reports-spurious-error-when-th-tags-appear-within-tbody-tags) to report this.

Comment: @Doug McClean: Any word on VS11's HTML5 validator? I'm not sure if it's any different from the VS2010 one.

Comment: @BoltClock I haven't had a chance to play with VS11 yet.

Comment: I could fix the warnings on VS2010 by changing the `html_5.xsd` and `xhtml_5.xsd`, based on Chris's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603241/html5-element-legend-occurs-too-few-times#answer-12912876). Open the file, find the line `<xsd:element ref="th" vs:disallowedancestor="tbody tfoot" />` and change it to `<xsd:element ref="th" />`.

Comment: The link to section 4.9.31 goes to the wrong place, seems to be a bad redirect on from w3.org. The intended content is at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#table-examples (article here on w3c working with whatwg at https://www.w3.org/blog/2019/w3c-and-whatwg-to-work-together-to-advance-the-open-web-platform/)

Comment: @Tone: Ah, yeah, I heard about that when it happened; I was surprised W3C was willing to swallow their pride. I've updated both links to point to the living spec.

Answer (score 14):

The HTML5 spec [only requires that it be inside a `tr`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-th-element), and the spec actually includes an example with a `th` nested inside a `tbody`.

Answer (score 5):

Generally a `TH` in a `THEAD` will have a `scope` value of `"col"` while a `TH` in a `TBODY` will have a `scope` value of `"row"`.