# HTML5 Element 'legend' occurs too few times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have the following View in MVC and I get the warning message: `Validation (HTML5): Element 'legend' occurs too few times`

```
@model Berwin.Models.ViewModels.UserViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Press";
}

<h2>Press Area</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "PressController", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName)
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company)
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.JoinMailingList)
</fieldset>
}
```

Would like to know why I am getting this warning and what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: I submitted this as a bug.. and it should be fixed in next version of VS: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782966/wrong-html5-validation-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To prevent Visual Studio incorrectly warning you that the `"Element 'legend' occurs too few times"` you need to correct Visual Studio's HTML and XHTML validation files.

VS will then treat the `<legend>` tag as optional inside a `<fieldset>` tag (as per the spec).

To do so, there are two files you need to edit: `html_5.xsd` and `xhtml_5.xsd`. For VS2010 these are found in (e.g.):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\`

Steps to take:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Using a text editor open the file `html_5.xsd` found in the folder above.
3. Locate the following line:

   *(note there are two lines which are similar, the first is correct, the second needs editing)*:

   > `<xsd:element name="legend" type="legendType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />`
4. Edit the line to read:

   > `<xsd:element name="legend" type="legendType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />`
5. Save the file
6. Repeat the process for the file `xhtml_5.xsd` which is in the same folder

Now start Visual Studio and view your HTML5 file - the warning will be gone.

I hope that helps others, and I hope the .xsd files will be corrected in a future update.

**UPDATE:**

The line you need to find may be:

> `<xsd:element ref="legend" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" vs:firstchild="true"/>`

If so, change the `minOccurs="1"` attribute to `minOccurs="0"`

Comment: Why the down vote...?! At least add a comment if you're going to downvote.

Comment: +1. As you stated correctly that the `legend` is optional and that Visual Studio is reporting it incorrectly. I know the accepted answer worked around Visual Studio's issue by simply adding a legend but in the end, why add an optional element you don't need? In that case I think the correct solution is to ignore the VS warning as it is incorrect or as you stated, "fix" VS. I do not know why someone would have downvoted this.

Comment: +1 for showing how to fix Visual Studio. The line I had to change was slightly different: <xsd:element ref="legend" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" vs:firstchild="true" />

Answer (score 23):

According the HTML 5 spec, the `<legend>` tag is not a required element within a `<fieldset>`.

> The legend element represents a caption for the rest of the contents
>   of the legend element's parent fieldset element, if any.

Docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-legend-element

In your case, its just a warning provided by Visual Studio or a plugin.  Its not required and there may be a way to supress the warning under Tools - Options - Text Editor - HTML - Validation.  Here you can also switch the target of your validation (HTML 5, XHTML 1, etc)

Comment: ha ha another -1 with no comment, you guys are a trip.  I may be wrong, but I'm just citing the spec witch answers why the OP would receive a warning when being validated against it.

Comment: I cant get rid of the warning. Tried several combinations in ...HTLM - Validation.

Comment: For those looking to update VS to correctly validate the `<fieldset>` tag see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12912876/834431

Answer (score 11):

Legend is optional in a Fieldset.

But try this, to get rid of the warning:

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName)
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: @danRhul Someone correct me if I'am wrong. But yes it's like a header for the fieldset.

Comment: This is not correct, the legend is NOT required in the HTML5 spec

Comment: @Verkion - I've also added instructions below as to how to quickly edit the .XSD files to correct Visual Studio's validation. Hope that helps others.

Comment: -1: Ihe legend element is optional and as VS should not generate a warning about it. The correct solution would be to simply ignore the warning. In my humble oppinion, adding an optional element one does not need to please VS's incorrect warning is a work-around at best. Don't add elements you don't need, specially if they are optional.

Comment: If you want the error to go away, this blog did the trick for me. http://philsversion.com/2012/08/17/element-legend-occurs-too-few-times/

Comment: Solution to correct VS2010's incorrect validation warning is in this answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12912876/834431

Answer (score 3):

Q: Why are you getting this warning? A: Because the Visual Studio HTML 5 validator mistakenly believes you need a `legend` in every `fieldset`. The `legend` "[represents a caption](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-legend-element)" for the other form elements and labels in a `fieldset`. It is **optional**.

As an aside, a `fieldset` is used to group form controls together. Since each of your `fieldset`s only contain a single form element, they aren't really "grouping" anything. Why not do away with all of them? For the short form you've shown us, I don't see a benefit to grouping a portion of these form inputs separate from the others. A `fieldset` makes a lot more sense when you have individual form elements that don't stand on their own and need to be grouped together. Example:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>How many lumps of sugar would you like?</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="lumps" value="1" id="lumps1" />
    <label for="lumps1">One lump</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="lumps" value="2" id="lumps2" />
    <label for="lumps2">Two lumps</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="lumps" value="0" id="lumps0" />
    <label for="lumps0">No lumps for me, thanks</label>
</fieldset>
```

Q: What do you need to do to fix this? A: I don't think it *needs* fixing at all. But if you want the errant validator message to go away, add a `legend` element as the first child to every `fieldset`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handled it was to simply hide the legend:

```
<fieldset>
<legend runat=server visible="false"></legend>
...
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score -2):

Where are you validating this?  The legend element is optional:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-fieldset-element

> Content model: Optionally a legend element, followed by flow content.
>
> The name of the group is given by the first legend element that is a child of the fieldset element, if any.

The legend element is a title for the fields within the fieldset and used as follows

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>My Title></legend>
  ...
</fieldset>
```

Which renders a box like this

```
-- My Title --------------
| ...                    |
--------------------------
```

Comment: ...Razor? Try looking at the tags

Comment: I know you're using Razor to create your view, but you didn't say whether it was Visual Studio giving you the error or another online validator like the W3C.  I'd suggest that Visual Studio's validator is wrong if it thinks the legend is required.